# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS - Nouveau errors booting Live USB

Tags: 16.04, nouveau

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS from a usb stick but during booting I get the following errors:

[image: Boot Errors]

There is something wrong with nouveau. I have GeForce 970 GTX but some time ago I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS without problems. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS is based on the 4.4 Kernel. As per [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944842/kernel-4-10-in-ubuntu-16-04-3-update) Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS uses Kernel 4.10.

As of Kernel 4.6 [a bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94990) was introduced for the Nouveau driver that isn't in the nVidia driver.

I understand the bug has been fixed but not sure why it is affecting you. I would recommend getting the latest image for 16.04.3 and trying that. Alternatively you can try the steps outlines in the Q&A to install 16.04.1 and doing an HWE upgrade to 16.04.3.

An alternative is to install 16.04.1 and follow this: [How do I update kernel to the latest mainline version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version/879920#879920).

I had no problem booting the Live USB with Nouveau driver but have the GTX 970M laptop chip with 3 GB RAM. The bug in question was for the 4 GB RAM model. FYI after installing 16.04.3 and then configuring Ubuntu with the nVidia driver it works fine on my platform:

[image: Peek Ubuntu 16.04.3]