# Can't boot into new kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, grub-efi

I updated my kernel via `apt-get`, but my Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot into it.
`uname -r` gives `4.8.0-36-generic`. `sudo update-grub` gives

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-98-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

But `sudo apt-get upgrade` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-gcp-tools-4.10.0-1007 linux-headers-4.10.0-37
  linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97
  linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-tools-4.10.0-1007-gcp
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The newer kernels seem to be installed, but grub doesn't find it?

Any ideas?

Comment: What kernel version do you think you updated to ?

Comment: I thought it would be 4.10.0-37-generic

Comment: Since `apt upgrade` say's that linux-image-4.10.0-37 is no longer required, something is worng. Try to look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/944842/kernel-4-10-in-ubuntu-16-04-3-updatehttps://askubuntu.com/questions/944842/kernel-4-10-in-ubuntu-16-04-3-update

Comment: @SorenA https://askubuntu.com/questions/944842/kernel-4-10-in-ubuntu-16-04-3-update

Answer (score 1):

Manually re-installing the newest kernel via `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` like it is recommended in [kernel-4-10-in-ubuntu-16-04-3-update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944842/kernel-4-10-in-ubuntu-16-04-3-update) solved the problem.