# How to change the custom installed kernel of my server

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

First it is not a duplicate question as I already tested the solutions I found using a Google search. Here are what I tested:

https://github.com/dannyti/sboxsetup/wiki/Changing-OVH-Server-Kernel
[Switching from OVH kernel to default kernel without reinstalling Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871336/switching-from-ovh-kernel-to-default-kernel-without-reinstalling-ubuntu)

If it is really a duplicate please tell what I did wrong.

So I have an Armhf server from SoYouStart (OVh) which comes with a custom Linux Kernel:

```
uname -a
Linux ns3087832.ip-54-37-26.eu 4.9.124-armada375 #1 SMP Mon Sep 3 19:18:09 CEST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The answers I found on the Internet suggest to install `linux-image-generic` and then change the grub config (removing 06_OVHkerne which I don't have). I did this but my server always boot with the custom kernel. Also grub wasn't installed so I installed.

Here some information that may help:

```
root@ubuntu /tmp [0|1]# ls -alh /boot/
total 44M
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Aug 14 15:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K Jun 22  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.4M Nov 15  2018 abi-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 226K Nov 15  2018 config-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  78K Sep  3  2018 config-4.9.124-armada375
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Aug 14 15:11 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  25M Aug 14 15:01 initrd.img-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   24 Nov 15  2018 retpoline-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3.6M Nov 15  2018 System.map-4.15.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 1.7M Sep  3  2018 System.map-4.9.124-armada375
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   24 Sep 24  2018 uImage -> uImage-4.9.124-armada375
-rw-------  1 root root 4.5M Sep  3  2018 uImage-4.9.124-armada375
-rw-------  1 root root 7.9M Nov 15  2018 vmlinuz-4.15.0-42-generic

root@ubuntu /tmp# sfdisk -l /dev/sda 
Disk /dev/sda: 5.47 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HUH728060AL
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FF5C3324-73F8-4ED1-B452-14B5AF1CC4ED

Device           Start         End     Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1           40        2048        2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sda2         4096    40962047    40957952   19.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3     40962048 11719991295 11679029248    5.4T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  11719991296 11721037823     1046528    511M Linux swap
```

How can I change the Linux kernel of my server?

Comment: "So I have an Armhf server from SoYouStart (OVh) which comes with a custom Linux Kernel:" I am confused... is this a virtual machine you rent from them? if so they are in charge of the kernel and the Ubuntu running on it. You need to ask them how to proceed ... and you are likely to be told you are not allowed as that kernel has alterations that are needed for that virtual machine to work. It would probably break your boot.

Comment: @Rinzwind It is a dedicated server. It came with an OS that uses a custom kernel.

Comment: What is the result of `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` please?